# sql condition as date and db date format is in datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I am trying to pass the date as a where condition in select query.but in the database the field is in datetime format.I don't know how to pass the condition?

```sql
SELECT * FROM (`scl_students`) WHERE `std_added_on` = '2015-03-03'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got it.

```
SELECT * FROM (`scl_students`) WHERE DATE(std_added_on) = '2015-03-06'
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is that the `std_added_on` contains time portion which could be non-zero. In order to select all rows for a given date you would write:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `scl_students`
WHERE `std_added_on` >= '2015-03-03'
AND   `std_added_on` <  '2015-03-03' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This is better than `` DATE(`std_added_on`) = ... `` performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

You convert datetime to date after u try to run query

Answer (score 0):

Use that query as this.

SELECT * FROM (`scl_students`) WHERE `std_added_on` = ('2015-03-03');

Answer (score 0):

The datetime format expects that you parse time value also.

Try doing the following code.

`SELECT * FROM (`scl_students`) WHERE`std_added_on`= '2015-03-03 00:00:00'`

Above query will only if your *std_added_on* value stored in database is = 2015-03-03 00:00:00

Comment: Alternatively you can change the std_added_on column type to date instead of datetime.